# Securing sensitive data while still allowing logged users to access it

Tags: php, security, encryption, public-key-encryption

I am currently analyzing the security needs of a client project (a PHP/HTML/CSS/JS web application built on Symfony). I have spent most of the day researching and reading on the subject, but I am still unsure of how to best fulfill these security needs.

### The premise

The client company has access to sensitive information about some of their clients. They need to be able to input this information in the application in order to have access to it later on. This sensitive information should be retrievable and decryptable by any user of the app who has the necessary privileges within the app.

It's also important to note that the end-users of the web application are not tech-savvy: they're regular folks with no training whatsoever in computer science or technology in general.

From my experience and from what I've read, I've gathered that the following best practices should be obeyed to obtain the best security:

- We shouldn't be storing any secret keys that can be used to decrypt the data anywhere on the server or database *(that makes sense to me, as an intruder could use them to decrypt just about everything)*.
- All of the decryption should take place on the client-side *(so we never even touch a private key, eliminating the risk of mishandling it)*.

I'm familiar with the concepts of asymetric encryption. Additionally, I learned about PHP's [`openssl_seal()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-seal.php) today, which seems like it could allow us to safely encrypt data while still allowing decryption by different users (who would each have their own set of public-private keys). But every option I could come up with still seemed like it fell short in one way or another.

### The questions

Here are the questions I ended up with:

#### How can the private key be safely stored by the users?

If each user has a set of keys that are generated client-side upon registration, how can these private keys be safely stored by the users? And how can they be reused later to decrypt data sent by the server?

The [WebAuthn](https://webauthn.guide/) spec and API provide a safe credential solution that doesn't require the user to save and manage certificates or private keys, but it's limited to authentication, so it doesn't seem like it can help us in this case.

Cookies and local storage seem to me like unsafe storage options for a private key like this. Temporary server side storage like the session doesn't seem any better, as it still leaves the key in the hands of the server.

#### How can data encrypted with `openssl_seal()` be updated to allow new public keys?

Obviously, all of the data could be decrypted and then re-encrypted with the new list of public keys. But that requires sending all of the data back and forth to a user with an existing private key, which seems a bit... unconventional.

Alternatively, perhaps the data could be encrypted with a set of keys that is stored on the server, but that is protected by a passphrase which itself would be encrypted with `openssl_seal()`. But that still leaves the encryption key on the server (albeit in an encrypted form).

#### Am I thinking about this completely wrong or misunderstanding a key piece of information?

I am here asking for help, so I think it's fair to say I am no security genius or expert. If I made incorrect assumptions or conclusions, or if I am looking at this the wrong way, please enlighten me: I am certain your feedback could be helpful to many others who are in similar situations.

---

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Unless you are building a full client-side application in JavaScript, I don’t know if PHP would benefit you  for more than an online note-storage system, based on your client-side decryption portion. If the decrypted data can’t touch your server, there isn’t a lot of logic that you can do server-side. Before building a secure system, it is usually a good idea to perform a threat analysis, and there’s a ton of things in there. What is the value of what is being secured? What resources could be used to go after it? Would you rather sacrifice the data than it be revealed?

Comment: Hey @ChrisHaas, thanks for the feedback! The threat analysis is actually what lead to securing the few specific pieces of data. I'm also open to moving these features or sections of the entirely client-side if it can help. But even with a fully client-side application, I am unsure of how to meet the constraints defined above.

Comment: Also, without going into too many details: the value of the data is quite high, but it's not a very highly targeted industry / client. And we would rather lose the data than have it revealed.

Comment: Thanks for your responses! Let’s start with server-side trust issues. Is it that the developers (or future developers) might not be trusted to always be acting in good faith? If so, someone could also sneak bad code into the client side. Is it about securing the server from outside? We have VPNs for that, and you can also lock down by IP. Is it PHP/Linux core bugs? Those would also allow client-side code to be injected. Then there’s one of your users going rogue.

Comment: I’ve never found a way to easily roll keys using seal or Samir’s secret sharing, it is a manual redistribute solution as far as I know. You might be able to build something, but that falls under “rolling your own” which is strongly discouraged in security. My point overall is that you might need to reset expectations with your team. I would detail out each threat, what they could do and what are the ramifications and remediations. I think it might also be good to bring in a full security professional so that they can find the things that you didn’t think out.

Comment: Thanks again for the help and clarifications. I'll take all of these into consideration, do some more research and see if I can talk to the team to revisit the basic assumptions and expectations. Consulting a security professional on this is definitely a good idea in this case. Cheers!